# Is a good graphics card important for remote desktop?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-control

I'm trying to pick a laptop for working from home, where I'll be using remote desktop to connect to my machine at work.  How important is it to have a good graphics card on the client machine (the laptop)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't all that important because your machine will be acting as a 'dumb terminal' because all of the rendering is preformed on the server you will be connecting to. Will you be using the Windows remote desktop or another solution such as VNC? I do believe that Windows Remote Desktop may preform some of the calculations on the clients machine for rendering window movements and such but nothing too serious.

Comment: Widnows Remote Desktop.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The experience will be slow, but it can be mitigated by picking options that minimize what must be exchanged over the 'net. Having a hot graphics card won't help this.

Comment: I actually get on very well with Remote Desktop,  as I use it mostly for non graphic work, it's slow when you try and use it with images, or where the backgrounds are textured.